# Json4s: Conversion to java.sql.Timestamp does not work

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, json4s

I have a case class Ab.

```
case class Ab(
   startTime: java.sql.Timestamp)
```

I get a JSON representation of this.

```
 {"startTime":"2014-12-12 11:12:12"}
```

Json4s apparently does not support Timestamp, so I created a custom serializer like:

```
case object TimestampSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Timestamp](format => (
  {
    case JString(s) => {
      Timestamp.valueOf(s)
    }
    case JNull => null
  },
  {
    case tm: Timestamp => JString(tm.toString())
  }))
```

However, when I try to extract the values, I get a mapping exception.

My code

```
org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse(""" {"startTime":"2014-12-12 11:12:12"} """).toString
//JObject(List((startTime,JString(2014-12-12 11:12:12))))
org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse("""  {"startTime":"2014-12-12 11:12:12"} """).extract[Ab]
//MappingException: No usable value for startTime
//Invalid date '2014-12-12 11:12:12'
```

Writing serializer like this works:

```
case object TimestampSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Timestamp](format => (
  {
    case JInt(s) => {
      new Timestamp(s)
    }
    case JNull => null
  },
  {
    case tm: Timestamp => JString(tm.toString())
  }))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Override the default dateFormatter. It is working for me.

```
case class Test(startTime: Timestamp)

implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
    override def dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  }

val t1 = parse("""{"startTime":"2014-12-12 11:12:12"}""").extract[Test]
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp extends java.util.Date. This means that your custom serialiser isn't invoked, but instead the standard Date serialiser, which uses a different format.

I see two solutions: Either you use your own timestamp class or you use a different serialisation format that works with the default Date serialiser.

Comment: I have written a custom serialiser for java.sql.Date exactly like above which works fine. Also, if I change to JInt(i) => new Timestamp(i), then also it works. So, I don't think, the issue is because of extending java.util.Date

Comment: The default date serialiser doesn't deal with JInts as they are partial functions it will then fallback to the CustomSerialiser, see S Karthik's answer on how to override the default behaviour (In your example your code was never called).